# Background on ios app not loading while testing

Tags: ios, xcode, background

I have my first app, but the background won't load, but only when I test it on my Ipod. When I test it on the simulator, it work fine.The app loads, but the background is black.

It gives me an error, but that error doesnt stop the app from compiling and running. Here is the error:
[image]

The files are all png, and they are all in the right place.

Here is how I implemented the background:
[image]
The files are all there, as seen here:[image]
Does anyone have any idea why this is doing that? I really want to publish the app, but have to get this fixed before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file has to be the same case as your call.  You have default.png in your call, Default.png for the file name.  It only matters on the device.

It doesn't matter in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks!!! It works!! It still gives me the same error, but the background loads fine.